# Find the equation of hyperbola whose foci are $F_1 = (3, 4)$ and $F_2 = (-1,-2)$ and $a=1$?

Tags: conic-sections

> Find the equation of hyperbola whose foci are $F_1 = (3, 4)$ and $F_2 = (-1,-2)$ and $a=1$?

I need some help with this exercise. I know that this hyperbola is not centered at the origin, but I don't know its orientation and consequently the form of its equation. Does the distance between the foci still $2c$ in this case?

Comment: Hint: What the midpoint of the two foci?

Comment: Us ethis definition : http://www.sparknotes.com/math/precalc/conicsections/section4.rhtml  OR  https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/conics/hypdef.html

Comment: @labbhattacharjee It's not that simple. The hyperbola is $45^\circ$ rotated. This will need a bit more work hence the potential cause why the OP is stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the definition, directly

$PF_1-PF_2=2a$

$$\sqrt{(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2}-\sqrt{(x+1)^2+(y+2)^2}=2$$
$$\sqrt{x^2-6 x+y^2-8 y+25}=\sqrt{x^2+2 x+y^2+4 y+5}+2$$

and square both sides
$$x^2-6 x+y^2-8 y+25=x^2+2 x+y^2+4 y+9+4 \sqrt{(x+1)^2+(y+2)^2}$$
Rearrange  and divide both sides by $4$
$$4 - 2 x - 3 y=\sqrt{x^2+2 x+y^2+4 y+5}$$
and square again
$$\color{red}{3 x^2+8 y^2+12 x y-18 x-28 y+11=0}$$
is the equation of the wanted hyperbola.

Hope this can be useful

$$...$$

[image]

Comment: Thank u so much, you saved my semester,hahah!

Answer (score 0):

We can easily find the center of the hyperbola to be $(1,1)$ which is the midpoint of the foci and the slope of the major axis is $\frac{3}{2}$ since the major axis passes through both foci.

We still have $c=\sqrt{13}$ as per usual since rotation does not affect the defining properties of the hyperbola or a conic for that matter. Hence, $b=\sqrt{13-1}=\sqrt{12}$.

So we know that the hyperbola is the curve $C_0$ rotated by $\arctan\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$ counterclockwise and translated by $(1,1)$ about the origin, where $C_0$:
$$x_0^2-\frac{y_0^2}{12}=1$$

I will leave the manipulations out. Eventually the curve should have the equation:
$$3x^2-18x+12xy-28y+ 8y^2+11=0$$